# Python 3 - Find two letters in same row

Tags: python, string, list, grid

I'm having troubles with being able to find out if two letters are in the same row of my 4x4 grid. For example, if i have the list

```
['GB','AB','CD']
```

I want to check if the letters GB are in the same row of the grid. Lets say the grid is for example,

```
['ABCD','EFGH','IJKL','MNOP']
```

Now GB is are not in the same row, but AB is and then so are BC and thats where im running into problems.

Comment: You mean this `[x for x in l if 'GB' in x]` ?

Comment: Does it matter if `G` and `B` aren't adjacent, or in the given order? Eg, is `'ABCG'` a match? Is `'GACB'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following:

```
grid = ['ABCD','EFGH','IJKL','MNOP']
seq = ['GB','AB','CD']
for seq_elem in seq:
  print any(seq_elem[0] in row and seq_elem[1] in row for row in grid)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Sorry for anyone else who posted solution, i did not try them, but im sure that they are all great!.

Answer (score 0):

```
grid = ['ABCD','EFGH','IJKL','MNOP']

def in_same_row(a, b):
    return any(a in row and b in row for row in grid)

in_same_row("G", "B")   # => False
in_same_row("A", "B")   # => True
```